# Rails generate url from array with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, routes, polymorphism

I wondered if there's some way to do this

```
polymorphic_path([@page, @image])
```

but like this

```
polymorphic_path([@page, :image_id => 1])
```

It's for the purposed of refactoring where I'd like to throw various params into the array and where they're null, they're ignored, but otherwise they generate the relevant nested url.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a larger example of parameters you wish to pass?

Comment: Well really that's as it goes. Say I have a page resource nesting an image resource I would ideally like to do something like Simone posted. Hey on another note I learned a lot from rboard, thanks for the awesome work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
polymorphic_path(:page_id => @page.id, :image_id => 1)
```

Comment: I get `nil_class_path' where I try that.